# Exclusive CSS selector

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am working on a page where the selected item among a list is characterized by NOT having a given class. Something like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">not selected</li>
  <li class="a b">selected</li>
  <li class="a">not selected</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to defined a CSS selector to grab the li node in the page having ONLY the a class.
Unsurprisingly the following statement is not enough:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li.a')
```

Because it returns ALL the *li* nodes having the *a* class.

Any experience on such scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In such case you may consider attribute selector like this:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">Select me</li>
  <li class="a b c d more classes">Don't select me</li>
  <li class="a b">Don't select me</li>
  <li class="a">Select me</li>
</ul>
```

Simply pay attention to extra spaces:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a ">Pay attention to this one !!</li>
  <li class="a b">Don't select me</li>
  <li class="a">Select me</li>
</ul>
```

But since you are using JS you can use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to get rid of the extra spaces:

```js
var elem=document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++)
  elem[i].className=elem[i].className.trim();

console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li[class="a"]').length)
```

```css
li[class="a"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a ">Pay attention to this one !!</li>
  <li class="a b">Don't select me</li>
  <li class="a">Select me</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from [Temanis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557233/10400050) you can use the `not` selector in this case

```
document.querySelectorAll('li.a:not(.b)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :not() pseudo, that's exactly what you need for this job.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

So all you have to do is

```
document.querySelector(".a:not(.b)")
```

But also consider using jQuery, like

```
$(".someclass").not(".another")
```

Stansard querySelector is faster, jQ is more readable.